# Reputation has turned red

Tags: support, reputation, user-experience

I've noticed that the reputation counter in the top navigation bar on Stack Overflow has turned red (it was green yesterday, and it's still green on Meta). Is that red colour trying to tell me something or is it a CSS hiccup?

[image]

Comment: A/B testing, see the dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I missed it - ty.

Comment: When was the last time you clicked on that thingy? O_o